# CakePHP 3 Retrieve associated data

Tags: cakephp

I want to get Shop data and also associated Comments with this Shop, but Comments contains also author_id which connected to Authors table.

How to get also not only Comments, but also and Authors data by author_id?

Its my Shops controller:

```
public function viewShop($slug = null)
    {
       $shop = $this->Shops->find('all')
                ->where(['slug'=>$slug])
                ->contain(['Comments']);


       $this->set('shop', $shop);
       $this->render('index');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First bind your Comment model with Author model as BelongsTo and then replace your code with this.

```
public function viewShop($slug = null)
    {
       $shop = $this->Shops->find('all')
                ->where(['slug'=>$slug])
                ->contain(array('Comment'=>array("Author")));


       $this->set('shop', $shop);
       $this->render('index');

    }
```

Comment: How did You get this? It's pretty easy :) Awesome! Thanks. What should I learn more, please advise me.

Comment: Hmmm, Practice.Just concentrate on concepts.

Comment: @VladyslavHavrylenko You should start with reading the docs from start to finish http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data